Converting Measurement Signal to Hexadecimal String in Lua for Excel Template Integration
I have a measurement signal that is diagnosed and  returns a positive numeric value. I need to convert this value to a hexadecimal string using Lua, integrated within an Excel template, and passed to Python. Here is the Lua code I've tried, but it's not working:
_lua(R"§("string.format("%8X", @measdata:Diag_DTC[1].max($tStep1,$tStep1End))")§")

The signal from the array, for example, @measdata:Diag_DTC[1].max($tStep1,$tStep1End) which equals 10555136, should be converted to A10F00.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

The issue with the current code is that it is unable to perform number conversation and formatting properly.
_lua(R"§(string.format("%08X", tonumber(@measdata:Diag_DTC[1].max($tStep1,$tStep1End)) or 0))§")


In your case tonumber() to convert the measurement value to a number, is not already in the correct format

string.format("%08X", ...) formats the number as an uppercase hexadecimal string, zero-padded to 8 characters


or 0 as a fallback in case the tonumber() conversion fails, to prevent errors.
Tip : Next time don't  add quotes around the entire string.format() call, as they were unnecessary and causing issues.
